# Some elements dont show up as members of a sequence in R when using %in% seq()

Tags: r, sequence

I am trying to check if values are present in a sequence of numbers using the %in% operator in R. The sequence is generated using the seq() function with a step of 0.01, ranging from 0.50 to 1.10.

Here are the different inputs I tried:

```
.55 %in% seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01)
.57 %in% seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01)

".55" %in% seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01)
".57" %in% seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01)

"0.55" %in% seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01)
"0.57" %in% seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01)

0.55 %in% seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01)
0.57 %in% seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01)
```

However, the outputs for these inputs are confusing and unexpected:

```
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE

[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE

[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE

[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
```

1. Does anyone know why .55 is recognized in the sequence, but .57 isn't?
2. How come when we add a leading zero and put quotes it returns TRUE?
3. How come quotes without a leading zero returns FALSE?

Comment: @AllanCameron, please post these as answers ...

Comment: Seems fair (although I guess finding a single dupe-target could be challenging).  Frustrating when answering is less effort than finding the appropriate dupe-target ...

Comment: @BenBolker you're right - there's no single exact duplicate that I can find. I'll post an answer and if anyone wants to close as a duplicate I won't mind.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your first question is that it is not safe to compare floating point numbers for exact equality - see ["Why are these numbers not equal?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

The answer to your second question is that the numbers in `seq` are converted to characters for the comparison, and the character output of the sequence is what is shown in the console if we do:

```r
as.character(seq(.50, 1.1, by = .01))
#>  [1] "0.5"  "0.51" "0.52" "0.53" "0.54" "0.55" "0.56" "0.57" "0.58" "0.59" "0.6" 
#> [12] "0.61" "0.62" "0.63" "0.64" "0.65" "0.66" "0.67" "0.68" "0.69" "0.7"  "0.71"
#> [23] "0.72" "0.73" "0.74" "0.75" "0.76" "0.77" "0.78" "0.79" "0.8"  "0.81" "0.82"
#> [34] "0.83" "0.84" "0.85" "0.86" "0.87" "0.88" "0.89" "0.9"  "0.91" "0.92" "0.93"
#> [45] "0.94" "0.95" "0.96" "0.97" "0.98" "0.99" "1"    "1.01" "1.02" "1.03" "1.04"
#> [56] "1.05" "1.06" "1.07" "1.08" "1.09" "1.1"
```

Note that the strings `"0.55"` and `"0.57"` are both present here.

The answer to your third question is simply that the strings `".55"` and "`.57`" *do not* appear in the above result.